# How should I use strcmp() to check whether a string is found in a larger string?

Tags: c, return, substring, c-strings, strcmp

The problem is pretty simple. I have to check whether a string is a substring of a string or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *a = "Aristotle was not a good a philosopher";
    int i = 1;
    if (strcmp(a, "good") < 0) {
          return i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use strstr?

Answer (score 2):

There is no great sense to use the function `strcmp`. Instead you should use the function `strstr`.

```
return strstr( a, "good" ) != NULL;
```

or

```
return strstr( a, "good" ) == NULL;
```

depending on what you are going to return if the string "good" is present in the string `a` or not.

Answer (score 0):

as Vlad from Moscow answered the correct way is to use `strstr`

if you need for some (unknown) reason to use `strcmp` then your code need a loop
(also note that `strcmp` return 0 in case the strings are the same)

something like the below (note there are no sanity checks below to check for example if the subset_string is shorter or longer then the original stream etc ..)

```
int main() {
char *a = "Aristotle was not a good a philosopher";
char *word_to_find = "good";
for(int i=0;i< (strlen(a)-strlen(word_to_find));i++) 
{
 if (strcmp((a+i), b) == 0) {
      return 0;
}
return 1;
```

}